# Sending email with image background

Tags: html, outlook, background-image, html-email

I am using Microsoft Flow to send an email that should have image as a background. So I created following code

```
<html> <body>     <div style="width:100%, heith:100%">
<div style= "position:fixed  ;  width:500px; height=500px; top:1%; left:1%; ">
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@{outputs('GifFile')?['body']['$content']}"  alt="My Background" width="500" height="600">  </div>

<div style= "position:fixed  ;   top:5%; left:5%; ">
  CONTENT <br/> More Content  </div> 
</div>
 </body>
<html> <body>
```

but in outlook (for Microsoft 365) it still shows text under the picture, where if I save the message source as html file - it shows text over the image, just as expected.

Also tried another code:

```
<html> <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
  </head>
<body>
  <div style="background:0 0/cover;background-image: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,R0lGODlhAwG2APeL ** Image code in here ** IBLAJCAA7') ;background-repeat:repeat;background-color:#ffffff;background-position:center;">
 <!--[if mso]>
    <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true">
      <v:fill type="tile" src='data:image/jpeg;base64,R0lGODlhAwG2APeL ** Image code in here ** IBLAJCAA7' color="#ffffff"/>
  </v:background>
<![endif]-->
<div>CONTENT <br>
   More Content</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how to show text over image in an email?
Thanks

Comment: welcome to HTML mail development. You will have to use tables if you want to support outlook. 90% of the stuff from HTML / CSS isn't supported there. Better to get a framework to create your HTML mails. https://mjml.io something like this.

Comment: Note that the `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

*The Outlooks* on Windows don't support background images. But you can use VML to mimick the feature. If you want a background applied to your entire window, the code should be as follow:

```
<div style="background:0 0/cover;background-image:url('https://www.example.com/image.jpg');background-repeat:repeat;background-color:#ffffff;background-position:center;">
    <!--[if mso]>
    <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" color="#ffffff"/>
    </v:background>
    <![endif]-->
    <div>CONTENT <br/> More Content</div>
</div>
```

Also, prefer linking to a hosted image instead of embedding an image in Base64. You can check detailed support in email clients for [background-image](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-background-image/) and [Base64 Images](https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/) on Caniemail.com.

Comment: Tried it, not working :(

Comment: Can you share your entire HTML code?

Comment: HTeuMeuLeu  - Added it in the question on the top

Comment: Thank you. As I mentioned, images embedded as Base 64 have poor support, especially in Outlook 365. Try hosting your image somewhere. Or refer to your image as a CID Embedded object inside the reste of your email code.

Answer (score 0):

Word (whcih renders emails in Outlook) does not support background images in the body. Try to use a table instead.